# SQL Server Comparison in same row

Tags: sql-server

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
I want to get max number in same row.

For example, this table is here

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Values_A |  Amounts_A  | Values_B |  Amounts_B  | Values_C |  Amounts_C| 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5000    |      50     |   3000   |     100     |   1000   |   200     | 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get maximum Values/Amounts in A or B or C.
In this case, A's Values/Amounts is 5000/50 = 100, B's Values/Amounts is 3000/100 = 30, C's Values/Amounts is 1000/200 = 5, So I want to get 100.

please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this concisely using `values` in a subquery:

```
select 
    (select
        max(val)
        from (values (Values_A/Amounts_A),
                     (Values_B/Amounts_B),
                     (Values_C/Amounts_C)
        ) t (val)
    ) max_val
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's `MAX()` function was designed to return the greatest number in a column from a collection of records, not columns.  I think the biggest challenge in your problem is that you have your data spread out across columns.  One approach is to unpivot this data using `UNION`, and then just select the maximum ratio.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Values_A / Amounts_A AS ratio
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Values_B / Amounts_B
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Values_C / Amounts_C
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT MAX(ratio)
FROM cte
```

This approach would work fine for a single record.  If you have multiple records in your table, then a more ugly approach is this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Values_A / Amounts_A AS A_ratio,
           Values_B / Amounts_B AS B_ratio,
           Values_C / Amounts_C AS C_ratio
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT CASE WHEN t.A_ratio > t.B_ratio
            THEN CASE WHEN t.A_ratio > t.C_ratio THEN t.A_ratio ELSE t.C_ratio END
            ELSE CASE WHEN t.B_ratio > t.C_ratio THEN t.B_ratio ELSE t.C_ratio END
       END AS max_ratio
FROM cte t
```